# Why did Zod not use some other planet for terraforming?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

**Why did Zod not pick Mars or Venus or whatever other planet elsewhere in the universe to make a new Krypton in *Man of Steel*?**

He had a terraforming machine that would've been equally effective somewhere else too.

Why risk fighting with all of earth and Superman (and potentially other superheroes) and causing complete genocide of the human race?

He already had Superman under his control on his ship, why not just extract the codex and fly away (or just nicely ask Superman to give DNA samples or whatever and assist in recreating his homeplanet)?

Was it all just for spite? Or because Earth has optimal distance from the Sun? Or some other pertinent reason(s) leaving Earth as the only option?

Comment: What if Zod was one of us?

Comment: Spite and vengeance

Comment: While terraforming like this might have massive destructive/transforming capabilities, I'd think it can't be just used on any planet. It probably has to have at least similar gravity, somewhat analogous atmosphere, distance from a star (or temperature range), maybe even our magnetic field that keeps us from getting nuked out by the solar winds, etc. Both moon and Mars have shown they can't hang onto much of an atmosphere.  Venus and Mars don't have magnetic fields. Planets that do have the field are all gas giants, I think.  Maybe moons of Saturn or Jupiter might work.

Comment: @AndrewMattson - couldn't Zod just plow into Mars and spin it's core to start up it's magnetosphere again?

Comment: FWIW he would have been Kryptoforming, not Terraforming.

Comment: @HannoverFist - sounds like more work than just destroying the Earth.  Plus, there is the problem with the gravity holding onto any terraformed atmosphere.

Comment: @hobbs - True dat.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As is indicated in the film, native Kryptonians are born genetically pre-ordained to certain roles within their society based on the codex, and for Zod that was to be a military commander. Zod not only excels in this role, he relishes it, it is every fiber of his being and existence. His single purpose in life is to protect Kryptonian society, and bring those who break its laws, fail to do what is best for it, or who seek to destroy it to justice as he sees fit, and in his eyes Jor-El is a heretic, a thief of the highest order, and his son the illicit and illegal offspring based on Kryptonian law, in addition to stealing the item he needed most from his coup: the codex.

His motivation isn't just spite for Jor-El and a desire to uphold Kryptonian law, there's also a sort of genocidal aspect to Zod's endeavors. Zod wants the codex so he can birth new Kryptonians who will follow his orders and uphold the version society he feels is best to continue the Kryptonian race, but since Kal-El isn't the product of the codex, Zod views Kal-El as genetically and therefore racially inferior. Given he's spent decades living among humans who have largely treated him as one of their own until certain recent events, coupled with them having virtually no way to stop him given his advanced technology, he likely views the terraforming and therefore "destruction" of earth as the ultimate solution to both his vision and his vengeance. Considering earth is also within what's referred to as a [Habitable Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstellar_habitable_zone) and occupied predominantly by a species they have no feelings for and can easily destroy, why *not* just take the planet?

Comment: I think he also says something to the extent of *"they will suffer for your deeds"* or something like that at some point.

Comment: Probably, but I haven't seen the movie since it was in theaters. Maybe I watched part of it on TV or via streaming, I dunno.

Comment: "Zod that was to be a **military commander** ... His single purpose in life is to protect Kryptonian society, and **bring those who break its laws**, fail to do what is best for it, or who seek to destroy it **to justice** as he sees fit"  No.  Just... no.  That's not what militaries do.

Comment: @RonJohn Perhaps human militaries (depending on country).

Answer (score 1):

Zod was still pissed off at Jor-El for stealing the codex and he doesn't care about humans or even certain Kryptonian bloodlines. He had no interest in going off to some other planet and he is not exactly the diplomatic type. Besides, the codex and the ancient scout ship with the genesis chamber were already on Earth. As far as he is concerned there is no point to leave.